# PowerBuilder application bundle. Hiding database info

Tags: powerbuilder

I am looking at a folder full of files.

1. Which file format is necessary should I decide to move to a new folder (client's computer).

> ```
> exe
> dll
> ini
> pbd
> pbl
> pbr
> pbt
> pbw
> ```
>
> As i know, when deploying a project, PB will create exe, dll, pbr and pbd according to what we've set. So I'm pretty sure these four file formats is necessary.
>   I also know that pbl and pbw are two files we use when working on a project. So these two file formats is unnecessary for the client (I assumed, correct me if I'm wrong).
>   I don't know about these two: pbt and ini.
>
> I do know that this ini file, namely klinik.ini is containing
>   private information. I don't know how to hide this file (I mean to
>   make the program to not depend on this file.) Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What you're asking isn't as generic as you're hoping. A lot of these extension types (including PBLs, which you are already thinking can be ruled out) can be answered "It depends on the app." The only ones I'd rule out as development only (and maybe it's just my lack of imagination; I never thought of a need to deploy PBLs until someone told me about their app) would be PBR, PBT and PBW. As for the rest, I'd look at the Application Techniques manual, which is distributed with PB and is also available at [the Sybase manuals site](http://sybooks.sybase.com).
2. The only dependency on this INI is coded into your application; it is not a PowerBuilder INI. If you want an alternate means of deploying this information, you'll need to change your application code.

Good luck,

Terry.